# How can I add a C++ DLL file in my .NET application?

Tags: c#

How can I add a C++ DLL file in my .NET application?

Answer (score 6):

You would use an "extern" function, marked with the [DllImport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.aspx) attribute.

```
[DllImport(@“C:\mylib.dll”)]
public static extern int myFunc(int param);
```

Answer (score 6):

Depending on the nature of the DLL, you can

1. [Add a reference to a registered COM DLL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx),
2. [Call Win32 DLLs with P/Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164123.aspx), or
3. Write a wrapper in [C++/CLI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163852.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If it's registered in COM, you can simply add a COM reference in Visual Studio and Visual Studio will do all the *Interop* creation for you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use Visual Studio, in your Solution right click "references" and choose "Add Reference".  Select your dll file.

In the classes that will use the dll, add :
using MyLibrarysName;

then you can call the functions in that DLL using 
Mylibraryname.myfunction

Comment: Yeah... thats exactly how to do it in simple step by step instructions. I dont understand why anyone would vote that down. +1

Comment: If the DLL is a C++ dll, add reference doesn't allow to add this reference. The error report says: "A reference to '<dll filename>'could not be added. Please make sure that the file is accessible and that it is a valid assembly or COM component.' The standard C++ value doesn't have an assembly, nor is it a COM component