# How to load a DLL in C#

Tags: c#

I currently have a DLL (done using C++). Now I want to load this DLL in my C# application to access some methods.

I tried using the example shown here but it couldn't work:
[Can I load a .NET assembly at runtime and instantiate a type knowing only the name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/465488/can-i-load-a-net-assembly-at-runtime-and-instantiate-a-type-knowing-only-the-na)

Any idea what's wrong? Is there any way to load a DLL and access the methods?

Thanks In Advance,
Perumal

Comment: have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14278/how-to-load-plugins-in-net

Comment: What's your error, what's details of your actions? ,...

Comment: What methods does the C++ DLL expose?  .NET, COM, or is it a WIN32 dll?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference between the question you linked to and your problem is that the other question was talking about a .NET assembly in .dll form, but your problem is about a native .dll file.

If you've got a lot of classes on the C++ side, it's best to use C++/CLI to wrap the native methods and classes. If your API only exposes methods, then you can get away with writing the bindings using [`DllImportAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.aspx) and the `extern` keyword.

This MSDN article should be a nice starting point for writing the bindings for your C++ dll: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2x8kf7zx(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 2):

1. First of all Right-Click in your solution explorer and select Add Refrence Tab.
2. Brose the dll you want add.
3. Add Dll to your code file using following fomat:

   using  in C# Or

   Import  in VB

If above solution doesn,t work then refer to this link:

[add C++ dll in .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223423/how-can-i-add-c-dll-in-my-net-application)

Comment: Thanks for the info. The code sample in your second link solves the issue.